# Twitter-Node Failing to Build Node.js (npm install twitter-node)

Tags: twitter, node.js

I am trying to install "Twitter-Node" (npm install twitter-node).  Version .3.2-pre of Node JS.

When I try and install I receive the follow error.  Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?  Seems like a pretty straight forward install to me.  I was able successfully install socket-io too...

```
m ERR! Error: twitter-node@0.0.2 preinstall: `./build.sh`
npm ERR! `sh` failed with 1
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/npm/0.2.12-    1/package/lib/utils/exec.js:25:18)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:34:17)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:164:12)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the twitter-node@0.0.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the twitter-node package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./build.sh
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple solution**

Just grab it from here:
https://github.com/patmcnally/twitter-node

The module on `npm` is old (last update August 31th) and ***broken by design***, it compiles its own base64 encoder instead of using Node's built in functionality.

To install:

1. Download the archive and extract it
2. cd into the folder and run `npm install .`
3. Have a nice day :)

**Old answer**

The install runs gcc to compile a `base64` module that depends on nodes `Buffer` class (the C++ implementation), since there were quite some changes to that in 3.x, it explodes!

```
Waf: Entering directory `/home/ivo/.local/lib/node/.npm/twitter-node/0.0.2/package/vendor/node-base64/build'
[1/2] cxx: base64.cc -> build/default/base64_1.o
../base64.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> base64_encode_binding(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../base64.cc:178: error: ‘class node::Buffer’ has no member named ‘data’
../base64.cc:178: error: ‘class node::Buffer’ has no member named ‘length’
../base64.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> base64_decode_binding(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../base64.cc:199: error: ‘class node::Buffer’ has no member named ‘data’
../base64.cc:199: error: ‘class node::Buffer’ has no member named ‘length’
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/ivo/.local/lib/node/.npm/twitter-node/0.0.2/package/vendor/node-base64/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx base64.cc -> base64_1.o}
```

[This commit](https://github.com/ry/node/commit/56074d1056a4e4b7a9954f18805605d79b0a5c3a) removed the two members and replaced them with static inlined methods.

In `.npm/twitter-node/0.0.2/package/vendor/node-base64/base64.cc` you need to replace the lines `177/178` and `198/199` which look like this:

```
Buffer *buffer = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Buffer>(args[0]->ToObject());
char *str = base64_encode((unsigned char*)buffer->data(), buffer->length(),&len);
```

With this:

```
Local<Object> buffer = args[0]->ToObject();
char *str = base64_encode((unsigned char*)Buffer::Data(buffer), Buffer::Length(buffer),&len);
```

Then run `npm rebuild twitter-node` and you're done! Don't use install, as it will re-download and overwrite the changes.

PS: I had to use `require('twitter-node@0.0.2')` to get it to import, since `npm` didn't create the symlink in `.local/lib/node` but you can easily fix that on your own.

**Update**

I did take a look at the module, this is hilarious, they compile a 80kb lib which is prone to failure with changed to Node.js just to use a base64 encode **ONE TIME**.

```
// Returns a Basic Auth header fit for HTTP.
var basicAuth = function basicAuth(user, pass) {
    return "Basic " + b64.encode(user + ":" + pass);
};
```

This does the exact same thing and doesn't explode on every other change to Node.js:

```
new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64')
```

Comment: Interesting... so when I browse into the .npm folder in file explorer (on ubuntu) I do not see a twitter-node folder there?  Any thoughts?  I posted a screenshot above you can see.

Comment: Strange, anyways I updated my answer with a much simpler solution, see the top :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  So whats the fix for me then?  I am trying to install via NPM.  Is that not going to work in this case?  Do I need to try and install it without NPM?  Not sure how to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: See my simple solution at the top of my answer, all you need to do is to download the newer version from the github repo and install that via NPM :)